# $f(x)=\|x\|_2$, $f_{\#}\mu=f_{\#}\nu\implies\mu=\nu$

Tags: measure-theory, pushforward

I want to show that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that are invariant under rotations and $f(x)=\|x\|_2=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^d x_i^2\right)$ sucht that the pushforwards are the same,i.e. $f_{\#}\mu=f_{\#}\nu$ then $\mu=\nu$. I understand that if the pushforwards are the same than the measure on the "annuli" of $\mathbb{R}^d$ will be the same. Also I understand that since the measures are invariant under rotations that if we cut the annulus (A) into $n$ small pieces (with one of these pieces called $P$) then $n\cdot\nu(P)=\nu(A)=\mu(A)=n\cdot\mu(P)$ so we get that $\mu(P)=\nu(P)$. So intuitively I can imagine that $\mu$ and $\nu$ will be the same. But I don't see how to make a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lebesgue%20differentiation,is%20named%20for%20Henri%20Lebesgue.) for finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the claim is a quick corollary of this result.

If you are not, one way to prove the claim is as follows:
let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family of Borel sets such that $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$.
You proved that this holds for annuli and "slices" of annuli. It's easy to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a Dynkin system. Thus, from [Dynkin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) it follows that
the $\sigma-$algebra generated by slices of annuli (let's call it $\mathcal{B}$) is contained in $\mathcal{A}$.
It's not hard to see that $\mathcal{B}$ contains the open balls, and thus it's the Borel $\sigma-$algebra, and so the two measures are equal.

**Edit:**

To see why $\mathcal{B}$ contains the open balls, one can use the following:
let $B$ be a open ball. First, suppose that $0\not\in\overline{B}$. Now, let $P:\Omega\to [0,2\pi)\times[0,\pi]^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ be the polar coordinates map (where $\Omega$ is a suitable region containing $B$ such that $P_{|\Omega}$ is a diffeomorphism).
Its easy to see that the slices of annuli get mapped to open $n-$cells and viceversa, while $B$ gets mapped to an open set $P(B)$. Since open $n-$cells  generate the topology, we can write  $P(B)=\cup_\mathbb N C_i$ (with $C_i$ the cells). Taking the inverse (which is well defined because $P$ is a diffeomorphism) we get that
$B=\cup_\mathbb{N} P^{-1}(C_i)$ and since $P^{-1}(C_i)$ are slices of annuli, we are done.

Now, let $B$ be general. If it contains $0$, we can cover a neighbourhood of it by a small ball centered in $0$ (which is in $\mathcal{B}$ as we now from the start), let us call it $B(0)$. For every $x\in \mathbb{Q}^n-\{0\}:x\in B$, let $r>0$ be such that
$B_{r/2}(x)\subset B_r(x)\subseteq B$. It is easy to see that if $0\not \in B=\cup_\mathbb N  B(r_i/2,x_i)$, otherwise $B=B(0)\cup_\mathbb N B(r_i/2,x_i)$ and we are done

Comment: thank you. I am having trouble to show that $\mathcal{B}$ contains the open balls. It seems clear that it contains the open balls centered at $0$, but it is not so clear to me that it contains the ones not centered at $0$.

Comment: @edamondo Take a open ball $B$. Let $x\in B$. Can you see why there is a slice of annulus contained in $B$ containing $x$? Can you iterate this process in order to obtain $B$ as a countable union of slices?

Comment: If I can find for every $x\in B$ a small slice $S_x\ni x$ of annulus contained in $B$, I could get $B=\cup_{x\in B} S_x$ but then I should use compacity which I don't have. So I am not sure how to cover the ball with countable many slices.

Comment: @edamondo I added a proof of the fact that $\mathcal{B}$ contains the open balls

Comment: thank you. I just don't get why "we can write we $P(B)=\cup_\mathbb N C_i$". Why is this a countable union and not in general an uncountable union?

Comment: @edamondo this is because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable (and similarly, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Now it is clear. With the other method (Lebesgue differentiation theorem) you pick a particular $f$ in $f(x)=lim \frac{1}{|B|}\int_B f(t)\mu(dt)$ to arrive to the result?

Comment: @edamondo The argument I had in mind is a little different: first, by Lebesgue-Radon-Nykodim, $d\mu=fd\nu+d\sigma$, with $\sigma\perp \nu$. Notice that this implies that, on the support of $\sigma$, $\lim \frac{1}{|B|}\mu(B)/\nu(B)=+\infty$ $\mu-$almost surely. This does not happen, thus $\mu\ll\nu$. Lebesgue diff. implies $f=1$. Also note that do not use balls for Lebesgue, but slices of annuli: this is ok as this is a family of bounded eccentricity.

Comment: very interesting. However I didn't get why $lim\frac{1}{|B|}\frac{\mu(B)}{\nu(B)}=+\infty$

Comment: @edamondo Apologies, I meant $\lim \frac{\mu(B)}{\nu(B)}$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882950/two-radon-measures-and-mutual-singularity) for more informations

Comment: I see. But then how do you use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem? I understand $\mu(B)=\int_Bf d\nu$. So $\frac{\mu(B)}{\nu(B)}=\frac{1}{\nu(B)}\int_B fd\nu$ then taking the limit with balls containing $x$ you get $f(x)$ on the right hand side but do we get $1$ on the left hand side? I am not sure if this is the way to proceed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122915/discussion-between-pelota-and-edamondo).

Comment: To use Dynkin's theorem you also need to note that the slices of annuli form a $\pi-system$ right?